# Web API 2 separate the request and response Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

We are developing some RESTful APIs using .NET WebAPI. There is one design decision the team is trying to make: should we always separate the request model and response model in the WebAPI level?

For example we have a endpoint exposing the customer resource:

`GET api/customers/1` returns the customer information (CustomerResponse)

`POST api/customers` accepts the customer information. (CustomerRequest)

Initially all the fields between those two models are the same except the response contains the `CustomerID` there which is not in the request.

I understand separating those two models will give us benefit by isolating the request/response since they can be different in the future. And the validation is happening on the request model only. However, it brings overhead as well since we need to maintain two models now.

I cannot find any standard there. Just want to see if there is any recommended best practices.

Comment: Yes, I have always separated those. Usually those two differ much more as time goes.

Answer (score 3):

I've found it easiest to separate the two out.
As mentioned, the two may diverge over time. For example POSTing a new resource probably won't have an id, but the response object does.

By separating out, you can:

1. Leverage the API frameworks Model validation (i.e. easily annotate which fields are required and optional). Which will return an error specifying which field is missing.
2. Leverage tooling (such as one of my favorites, Swashbuckle https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) which auto generates documentation from your routes and models. 
   The Documentation will not look good if request and response fields are bunched into the same Model.